# Scrollable Relative Layout does not show the bottom most part of the layout

Tags: android

I have a scrollable Android layout which is defined by the following code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"        
    android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_rule_in_registration" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/advertising_image"
            android:layout_width="306dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/inno_luck_sample_advertisement_picture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advertiser_name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertising_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/business_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_name_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_description_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/business_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advertiser_contact_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/ad_description_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advertiser_address_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_contact_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/advertiser_website_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_address_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_ok_btn"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_website_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_button_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/next_clr"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However as the picture below shows, this does not show the bottom most part of the layout.

[image: Android screen]

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: are you able to scroll the list?

Comment: It's not a list but yes I can do the scrolling.

Comment: don't use wrap_content with scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give padding in your Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp" 
android:paddingBottom="10dp">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:layout_below="@id/horizontal_rule_in_registration" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/advertising_image"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/inno_luck_sample_advertisement_picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/advertiser_name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/advertising_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/business_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_name_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ad_description_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/business_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/advertiser_contact_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ad_description_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/advertiser_address_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_contact_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/advertiser_website_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_address_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/register_text_clr"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_ok_btn"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/advertiser_website_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/next_button_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/next_clr"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps

Comment: are you facing still same problem?

Answer (score 1):

try this for your `ScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
....
```